# Jhipster UAA External Client

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

I use jhipster UAA and Gatewy App in my server running in EC2. 
(https://www.jhipster.tech/images/microservices_architecture_detail.002.png)

I have application running external cloud to put data in this server, It use REST endpoint to make request.

I need turn on security in this endpoint, then use access token or client secret.

I turned on the security, and copy my secret token by FrontEnd application. My first request work, but the second request don't work.

My OAuth2RestTemplate.

```java
 @Bean
  public OAuth2RestTemplate redditRestTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails, OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
    clientContext.setAccessToken(new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(applicationProperties.getAccessToken()));
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
    AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(
      Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider>asList(
        new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider(),
        new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider(),
        new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider())
    );
    template.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);
    return template;
  }
```

My request.

```java
OAuth2RestTemplate b = a.getBean(OAuth2RestTemplate.class);
String c = b.getForEntity("https://cloud.com/api/app/v1/events", String.class).getBody();
```

First request Ok.
I need save the new accessToken?

Is there any way to do this integration using "client secret" or anything?

Answer (score 0):

After making the authentication request `/auth/login` you have to save the `accessToken` received in the response. Subsequent requests must contain this access token in the header `Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>`

Comment: Hey @dondragon.
Thanks for you response, but I didn't express myself right.
I need connect machine to machine. One machine be in my cloud and another machine in my client.

I need "send" token to me partners for He make request in my cloud.




I